Adaptable size of a CardLayout-managed panel
While using CardLayout, I encountered a small problem with its size
If I don't set a preferred size explicitly (or set it to null), CardLayout seems to set preferred size of its managed container to the size of the container's biggest child component
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        JComponent narrowTextArea = new JLabel("Narrow label");
        cardPanel.add(narrowTextArea, "narrow");
        JComponent wideTextArea = new JLabel("<html>Wide label<br>wider and wider<br>one more line</html>");
        cardPanel.add(wideTextArea, "wide");
        frame.add(cardPanel);
        JButton cardSwitchButton = new JButton("Switch cards");
        cardSwitchButton.addActionListener(e -> cardLayout.next(cardPanel));
        frame.add(cardSwitchButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


If I do set a preferred size, then it's set in stone, even when it makes sense to grow a little to fit a bigger card
cardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 10));



If I set it to new Dimension(-1,-1), it simply shrinks into nothing
cardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(-1, -1));


How do I make the size of a CardLayout-managed panel automatically adjustable as cards with varying sizes get picked?
Other than attaching listeners and manually make it shrink/grow, hopefully, but I'll take anything at this point

The point of using a CardLayout is to keep the space the same size so other components or the frame do keep resizing every time you swap a panel. As a user this is what I expect. If this is not what you want then you need to revmoe/add components to the panel manually and then make sure you revalidate() and repaint() the panel or pack() the frame.

Each card of a CardLayout should have its own JPanel.  Each JPanel should have its own layout manager.

Oops, I can't type. My original comment should have said: "...the frame don't keep resizing..."

@camickr what if you need to shuffle around cards of varying sizes?

I guess my suggestion wasn't clear. If you need the panel size to change then you can't use the CardLayout. Instead you could use a FlowLayout, or BorderLayout and then manually remove (the existing panel) and add (the swapped panel) and then pack() the frame.

@camickr I don't like the sound of it. Manually adding and removing components after the parent has been painted seems wrong. CardLayout appeared to address exactly the need for swapping a container's children without manually putting them in and out all the time

The CardLayout is exactly what you use for swapping child panels if you want the size of each panel to be the same. You have stated you want the parent panel to shrink/grow depending on which child panel is visible. This is NOT how CardLayout works, so you can't use the CardLayout. Multiple people have suggested that you don't try to do this. If you want to do it yourself you have two choices: 1) remove/add child panels. 2) change visibility of child panels. You then need to "pack()" the frame. This is NOT the functionality of a layout manager. It is custom code.

@camickr it should've had some adaptableSize property, definitely

Original Answer
I rearranged your code to create the following GUI.

Left-clicking the Switch cards button shows the following card.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.
All Swing applications must start with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the Event Dispatch Thread.
I separated the code into separate methods so you can see how each step is done,  As I said in my comment, each card of the CardLayout requires a separate JPanel.  It's a good idea to get into the habit of placing Swing components on JPanels.
Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardLayoutExample());
    }

    private CardLayout cardLayout;

    private JPanel cardPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.cardPanel = createCardPanel();
        frame.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createCardPanel() {
        this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

        panel.add(createCard1Panel(), "narrow");
        panel.add(createCard2Panel(), "wide");

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createCard1Panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel narrowTextArea = new JLabel("Narrow label");
        panel.add(narrowTextArea);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createCard2Panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel wideTextArea = new JLabel("<html>Wide label<br>wider "
                + "and wider<br>one more line</html>");
        panel.add(wideTextArea);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton cardSwitchButton = new JButton("Switch cards");
        cardSwitchButton.addActionListener(e -> cardLayout.next(cardPanel));
        panel.add(cardSwitchButton);

        return panel;
    }

}

Edited to add 1
The OP wanted a GUI that changes size with different JPanels.  I think that this is an awful user experience.  I removed the CardLayout and built an array of JPanels that I switch.
Here's the complete runnable code to change the GUI size with each JPanel.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AwfulUX implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AwfulUX());
    }

    private int panelIndex;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel currentCardPanel;
    private JPanel[] cardPanels;

    public AwfulUX() {
        this.panelIndex = 0;
        this.cardPanels = new JPanel[2];
        this.cardPanels[0] = createCard1Panel();
        this.cardPanels[1] = createCard2Panel();
        this.currentCardPanel = cardPanels[panelIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(currentCardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel changeCardPanel() {
        panelIndex++;
        panelIndex %= cardPanels.length;
        currentCardPanel = cardPanels[panelIndex];
        return currentCardPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createCard1Panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel narrowTextArea = new JLabel("Narrow label");
        panel.add(narrowTextArea);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createCard2Panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel wideTextArea = new JLabel("<html>Wide label<br>wider "
                + "and wider<br>one more line</html>");
        panel.add(wideTextArea);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton cardSwitchButton = new JButton("Switch cards");
        cardSwitchButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            frame.remove(currentCardPanel);
            frame.add(changeCardPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
        });
        panel.add(cardSwitchButton);

        return panel;
    }

}


But, as it seems from your first screenshot, it doesn't shrink/grow automatically, does it?

@demavi: No, the JFrame doesn't change size.  It's as large as the largest JPanel.

I mean the whole point was to make the panel shrink/grow automatically according to the size of the current card. How is it functionally different from my snippet in that regard?

@demavi: See my updated answer.

Why do you believe it's awful user experience? Don't you mind that empty space on the first picture? I do, for one

@demavi: Left-click the button about 60 times, once per second, and see if you feel the same way,
